# The code is taking only the input for the first test case

Tags: c++14

//this code is accepting only the first input from the user even if there are multiple test cases provided.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    { 
      int t,n,ans,a, b, d, c, i,j; 
      cin>>t;
      while(t>0)
      { 
       c=0;
       cin>>n; 
       d = n;
       while(n!=0)
       {
         a = n; n=n/10; b = a % 10;
         if (d % b == 0)  c++; 
         else continue; 
       }
       cout<<c<<"\n";
       t--; 
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Aside from the ghastly code "style", you're using `std::cin` only once outside of any loop.

Comment: The code works well (i.e accepts multiple inputs) after removing inner or second while loop. So can you please elaborate? Also, your suggestion to improve the code style will be of great help. @Quentin

Comment: That's because I'm sleep-deprived and didn't see the `cin>>n;` line, my bad. About code style: ditch [`<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), indent and space your code consistently to make it more readable, use descriptive variable names, declare variables in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: @Quentin Yes I will keep the points in mind. So now, that you saw the `cin>>n;` line, please tell the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I actually can't reproduce your issue. What input are you using? Note that your algorithm does not work for numbers with zeroes such as `10`, it will trigger UB.

Comment: @Quentin Exactly. I checked its not working only for inputs with '0'. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Because `d % b` when `b` is zero is undefined behaviour. You need to check for that case and react accordingly. By the way, [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vWw2pb2R8BHVsgit) is a refactored version of your code to match what one would expect a C++ version to look like. The fix is on lines 24-25.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah.  I just added `if(b==0) continue;`, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `while(t>0)` with `while(t--)` and remove the `t--;` in the same `while` loop

Comment: I had tried this earlier also. Same issue after doing this also.

Comment: Checked your code, this is working fine and exits on 0 too so their seems no issue

Comment: I tried it on different compilers, but it did not work.